# Remove all extra space around a button with an image?

Tags: winforms, button, custom-controls

Alright, try as I might, I cannot for the life of me get rid of this tiny little border around my buttons.

**Edit:  I should mention, in case I didn't make it clear, these are buttons with an image on them, set to flat with the button sized to the image.**

Images below:

[image]
Number one, I can't for the life of me get these borders to GO AWAY.  I've checked everything I can think of.  They're:

- flat
- border 0
- no margins
- no padding
- manually sized to the size of the image (75px)
- in a table layout where the columns are all:

  - manually sized to the width of the image (75px)
  - borderless

Nothing seems to really "work" to get rid of these.  If I size the columns down to be 74px instead of 75px, most of them go away, but a few remain.  I've triple and quadruple checked the images, and they don't have anything that I can pick up on that should be causing this...  no transparency around the borders, definitely no border that looks like that.

Which leads me to the second problem:

[image]

Settings button when dialog is small...

[image]
Settings button when dialog is stretched out.

Settings button is also in the same table layout panel.

I've checked all the settings on the table layout panel as well..  I can't find any padding or margin or anything settings that suggest this should be happening.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  What am I missing..?

Comment: When all else fails... Control.Region

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: using directly a **PictureBox** as if it was a button. You can change your image on mouse over or mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Toolbar/strip/whatever it's called these days? Probably not going to help as I believe it pads on your behalf, but worth a shot.

In the end you can toss the buttons in the trash and write your own control. A single control that manages N buttons will work well here.

I don't understand your second problem. What's the problem? It'll be fixed if you roll your own control anyhow.

Comment: This isn't intended to be a toolbar/strip, they're supposed to look like tabs.  A tab control isn't quite suitable because of issues I had with how it looked in XP using the skin the client designed.  So buttons that simulate tabs (they trigger the hiding and showing of panels) it is.

The buttons are actually custom controls; I've got a temporary fix going by overriding OnPaint and just drawing it myself but this causes issues elsewhere, as I have other instances of those controls elsewhere in the app.  When a dialog with them is being resized they don't always redraw properly.

Comment: also the second problem is the button with the little gear develops the "white line padding" syndrome when the dialog is stretched out.  (Note it's fine when close together though?)

Comment: This is the problem with WinForms: Controls are not only expensive (there are system resources allocated with every single control), they don't like to exist back-to-back without issue. Every control is a system window object and each is a little island unto itself. When you need to pack "controls" together pixel perfect, or you need your app to perform better, the solution is (usually) creating a single control that provides the look and functionality of the fiddly bits inside (buttons in your case). How many "controls" do you think make up the widgets on an Office Ribbon? Precisely one.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't somehow cludge the stock controls into working the way you want, but if you want to do it "right", do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

While not a fix for the spacing issue, as a workaround you can make that gray gradient currently "behind" the "tabs" and control panel image into a `BackgroundImage` for the `TableLayoutPanel` using `BackgroundImageLayout` of `Stretch`. While not fixing the spacing issue, it would make it unnoticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a winforms control has its challenges (experience speaking here). I would agree that that is whats needed however. Depending on your project you may consider using XAML and WPF. It provides that fine detail you seem to be looking for in you application.

There are ways to host XAML controls in a winform app, but if you went this route it would be best to create a native WPF application. The reverse is also true (winform controls in a WPF app).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the image has transparent pixels around the graphic pixels you want?

May be a simple crop solution.